# $H$ field inside a paramagenetic medium less than outside it?

Tags: electromagnetism

If I have a coil with $N$ turns carrying a current of $ i$,  and the coil is wrapped around a paramagnetic core with $\mu  > \mu_0$,  does that imply the H field outside the coil is greater than the H field isnside the coil since $H = \frac{B}{\mu}$

Answer (score 1):

First of all, paramagnetic materials have $\mu > \mu_0$. Materials with $\mu < \mu_0$ are diamagnetic.

Second, we need to carefully define the points at which we are comparing the H-fields, since in general fields can have (sometimes quite complicated) spatial variations. For a coil wound around a cylindrical piece of paramagnetic material, call the H-field along the axis of the cylinder just outside the top of the cylinder $H_{out}$, and just inside the top $H_{in}$. Assume for the sake of convenience that these are positive.

By the continuity of the normal component of $\vec{B}$, we have
$$ \mu H_{in}=B_{in}=B_{out}=\mu_0H_{out} $$
$$ H_{in} = \frac{\mu_0}{\mu}H_{out}=\frac{1}{\mu_r}H_{out}. $$

For a paramagnetic material, since $\mu_r > 1$, $H_{in} < H_{out}$.

First of all, paramagnetic materials have $\mu > \mu_0$. Materials with $\mu < \mu_0$ are diamagnetic.

Second, we need to carefully define the points at which we are comparing the H-fields, since in general fields can have (sometimes quite complicated) spatial variations. For a coil wound around a cylindrical piece of paramagnetic material, call the H-field along the axis of the cylinder just outside the top of the cylinder $H_{out}$, and just inside the top $H_{in}$. Assume for the sake of convenience that these are positive.

By the continuity of the normal component of $\vec{B}$, we have
$$ \mu H_{in}=B_{in}=B_{out}=\mu_0H_{out} $$
$$ H_{in} = \frac{\mu_0}{\mu}H_{out}=\frac{1}{\mu_r}H_{out}. $$

For a paramagnetic material, since $\mu_r > 1$, $H_{in} < H_{out}$.

**Edit:** To further address your question about how a magnetic core "concentrates" $\vec{B}$, suppose you wind a long coil wound around a magnetic core, but with an air gap between the coil and the core. We can compare $\vec{B}$ within the magnet and just outside the magnet, inside this air gap. This time we are comparing H-fields not at the top of the long cylindrical core but at the surface near the middle of the cylinder. The B- and H-fields here are approximately axial. The tangential (in this case axial) component of $\vec{H}$ must be continuous, so we have
$$\frac{B_{in}}{\mu} = H_{in} = H_{out} = \frac{B_{out}}{\mu_0} $$
$$B_{in}=\frac{\mu}{\mu_0}B_{out} = \mu_r B_{out} > B_{out}. $$

Comment: But. I thought magnetic cores concentrate magnetic fields..

Comment: A magnetic material, usually a ferromagnet with large $\mu$, "concentrates" $\vec{B}$ in the same sense that an electrical conductor "concentrates" current density $\vec{J}$. A magnetic circuit is analogous to an electric circuit, with $\vec{B}$ corresponding to $\vec{J}$ and $\vec{H}$ to $\vec{E}$. Basically, a small $H$ can cause a large $B$ in the magnetic core. Another way of looking at it is a small magnetomotive force (mmf, in ampere-turns) can drive a larger magnetic flux if the core has large $\mu$ and hence is less "magnetically resistive" (low reluctance).

Comment: Not sure what you mean by that. If you are driving a constant current through the coil but insert a magnetic material through the coil, $\vec{B}$ within the coil will increase. How can $\vec{B}$ be concentrated in a magnetic material if it is unaffected by the material? The permeability of the magnetic core affects both $\vec{B}$ and $\vec{H}$.